# Git rebase took me to an old version and my code won't build

Tags: git, github

I have 2 branches where I work. Namely, testing and master. 
My testing branch is upto date as I mainly work on that. I have been committing my code regularly and had created timely pull requests so my code is safe on the cloud.

I created a pull request in a remote repository but there were some conflicting files and I was asked to revert (keep the original repo code). I was suggested to rebase, revert and create the pull request again.

Being on the testing branch, I rebased my master branch and now my code doesn't run. The command that I used was `git rebase testing master`. Now, I am at a very old commit and no matter how many times I tried to revert to my latest commit using `git revert <commit hash>` my code still doesn't show the last changes. It says

[image]

Can someone please help me out. I don't want to lose my code.

Comment: Does your original `testing` branch still exist? Check out the tip of the `testing` branch. Once you have that, your changes are "safe". Push that branch to the cloud for a remote backup. Then, create a new branch at that same commit called `testing-rebase`. Use *this* branch to do all of the rebasing you want. Resolve out the conflicts. Mess up a few times. Revert and retry. But always with your original changes safe on another branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git rebase testing master`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) means; replay the commits of `master` on top of `testing`.

That is not what you want to do when updating a PR branch: you want to replay your `topic` commits on on top of `master`. See [Git Branching - Rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

```
git rebase master topic
```

Reset your `topic` branch to the one you pushed previously:

```
git checkout topic 
git reset --hard origin/topic
```

Then try again.

---

As an illustration, from the [`git rebase` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description):

> Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "`topic`":

```
      A---B---C topic
     /
D---E---F---G master
```

> From this point, the result of either of the following commands:

```
git rebase master
git rebase master topic
```

> would be:

```
              A'--B'--C' topic
             /
D---E---F---G master
```

> NOTE: The latter form is just a short-hand of git checkout topic followed by `git rebase master`. When rebase exits `topic` will remain the checked-out branch.

Comment: Hey @VonC , I just noticed, I followed your exact commands but now I am unable to run any commands.

It shows,

It seems that there is already a rebase-merge directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
case, please try
 git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
If that is not the case, please
 rm -fr "/Users/Isha/Documents/oodd/AssignmentCode/Assignment3/OSS_Project/servo/.git/rebase-merge"
and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something

Can you help me.

Comment: Strange. Can you ask a new question, illustrating your new situation?

Comment: That looks like a rebase in progress, which means you need to follow the instructions, and check first your git status. Maybe there are merge conflict pending.